# TypeError: a float is required-other

Tags: python, typeerror

That's the way I tried to do this:

```
Trans=Raster("tsw")
Eair=0.85*(-log(Trans*1.00,e))**0.09
```

---

```
(ERROR) TypeError: a float is required
```

I have checked the path of data named 'tsw', and i have tried to make 'trans'block into a floating point number such as `Trans=float(Trans)`, but i've had no luck. Can anyone help?

Comment: Which imports are you using?

Comment: Does the `Raster` class define what should happen when it is multiplied by a floating point number?